# How to acquire the time of day information?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to read the time of day data from my computer using Excel's VBA editor and then parse the data into **independent integers** recording year, month, day, hour, minute, second separately.

In C# the function would be `DateTime.Now`; is there a VBA equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

This should get you going:

```
Sub ShowTime()

    Dim myYear As Long
    myYear = Year(Now)
    Debug.Print myYear

    Dim myMonth As Long
    myMonth = Month(Now)
    Debug.Print myMonth

    Dim myDay As Long
    myDay = Day(Now)
    Debug.Print myDay

    Dim myHour As Long
    myHour = Hour(Now)
    Debug.Print myHour

    Dim myMinute As Long
    myMinute = Minute(Now)
    Debug.Print myMinute

    Dim mySecond As Long
    mySecond = Second(Now)
    Debug.Print mySecond

    Debug.Print Now

End Sub
```

Comment: Your sub is hiding the built in `VBA.DateTime.Time` property. You also implicitly declare everything but `mySecond` as `Variant`.

Comment: @Comintern fixed

Answer (score 3):

The `VBA.DateTime` module has everything you need.

As in Visual Studio, the VBE has its own *object browser* (<kbd>F2</kbd> takes you there) - if you look at the contents of the `VBA` standard library, you'll notice a module named `DateTime`:

[image: Object Browser]

As with all standard library modules, `VBA.DateTime` members live in global scope, so you don't have to explicitly qualify them:

```
Debug.Print Now
```

Outputs exactly the same thing as:

```
Debug.Print VBA.DateTime.Now
```

...unless you have functions in your own project with identical names.

In C# `DateTime.Now` returns a `DateTime` *struct*, so you just do `DateTime.Now.Year` to get the year - however in VBA you can't call member methods on value types. Instead you use the `VBA.DateTime` module functions to retrieve each date part; they all take a `Date` parameter - [Wujaszkun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656557/1188513) shows them in action.